# How can i Bind or copy one input value into another input using of angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

- Hi all i am using MEAN stack in my Web portal with AngularJS as my front-end,
- In my portal i want to upload user profile image, so i have used `uplodcare`platform to upload the images in my portal.
- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p4OTqC5NQi83SKCBjfpr?p=preview)
- after chooses the Image we get that image url in `upload input`, then we need to Bind or copy these url value into below input to store in a backend. so we tried to get the solution like `ng-bind="userimg=img" value="{{img}}"` which is not working. please check and update us thanks.

**My Code :-**

```
<div>
    <label >Upload Img</label>
  <input ng-model="img" role="uploadcare-uploader" name="content" data-public-key="240426036fd9daf2d723" data-images-only />

</div>

<div>
    <label for="quantity">Fetch above input value in this input</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userimg" ng-bind="userimg=img" value="{{img}}">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one temporary solution for your question as you are using angularJS 1 version

```
   <div>
      <label >Upload Img</label>
      <input id="fileId" role="uploadcare-uploader" name="content" data-public- 
       key="240426036fd9daf2d723" data-images-only />  
   </div>
   <div>
     <label for="quantity">Fetch above input value in this input</label>
     <input type="text" ng-model="userimg">         
     <input type="submit" value="Set">
   </div>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.userimg = null;
$(':submit').on('click', function() {
  var input = $('#fileId');

  $scope.userimg = input[0].value;
  $scope.$apply();
})
```

On click of set button, you will get the value.
As you are using this library **https://ucarecdn.com/libs/widget/3.3.0/uploadcare.full.min.js** I can give this temporary solution

if you are using angularJs 1 any version then use angular-uploadcare library

**https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare**

and if you are using angular 2 or above version then use ngx-uploadcare-widget
**https://github.com/uploadcare/ngx-uploadcare-widget**

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer i know you have tried many times to get the solution, if possible update my plunker as well to know the exact solution thanks...

Comment: Hi Mani, But i can't update your plunker, as i don't have permission to update it.

Comment: if this answer is useful to you, can you please mark it as answered. Thanks Kusum

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer it's working perfectly in local host but while pushed into server showing error like `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng-uploadcare due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ng-uploadcare' is not available!`  if you have solution for this let us know thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just have to display the `img` variable in the text field for `<label for="quantity">`.

In ts file declare a variable `img`

```
 img;
```

In html file

```
<div>
     <label >Upload Img</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="img" role="uploadcare-uploader" name="content" data-public-key="240426036fd9daf2d723" data-images-only />

    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="quantity">Fetch above input value in this input</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="img" value="{{img}}">

    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer if possible please update my plunker as well tto know the exact answer...i have tried your answer but it's not working for me that's why, please update the plunker...thank you so much...

Comment: This is Angular 2+ style, I believe the question needs an answer in AngularJS